# Modeling multiple post types

Tags: c#, models

Let me give a great example which will illustrate my problem.

Let's say I am building an application where many users can post different type of 'posts' (i.e. Photo, Status, etc). Let's just use Photo and Status for this case.

I will show you how I am currently modeling my data, and if this can be improved (and what I am doing wrong)

I have a generic Post class:

```
public class Post<T>
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public User Owner { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public PostType Type { get; set; }

    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have a PostType enum:

```
public enum PostType
{
    Photo,
    Status
}
```

Then I have my respective Photo and Status classes

```
public class Photo
{
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public int Width { get; set; }

    public int Height { get; set; }
}

public class Status
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

I know that if I pursue my current solution to modeling this data, I will run into problems.

I have already hit some pain points, such as **how do I return the latest 25 posts, regardless of type** and also **how do I return a specific post by Id** without specifying the type of post(because the user shouldn't care.

Am I modeling my data COMPLETELY incorrectly? If so, do you have any suggestions for improvement?

Answer (score 1):

Both of your problems could be solved by having a base class independent of the post type:

```
public abstract class Post
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public User Owner { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public PostType Type { get; set; }
}
```

Your `Post` class can then inherit from it:

```
public class Post<T> : Post
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

The methods that should return any type of post can still return the correct type but the caller will access them as the base `Post` type and cast them when needed:

```
Post GetPostById(int id);
IEnumerable<Post> GetLatestPosts(int count);
```

Answer (score 0):

> how do I return the latest 25 posts, regardless of type

You can't, because in your design there is nothing common between a `Photo` and a `Status`, your have a generic `Post<T>`, but here `T`s can't be proceeded in a batch. A better design would be something like this:

```
public interface IPostable
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    PostType PostType { get; }
}

public class Photo : IPostable
{
    //special properties for photo
    public string Url { get; set; }

    //implement the interface
    public PostType PostType { get { return PostType.Photo; } }
}

public class Status : IPostable
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public PostType PostType { get { return PostType.Status; } }
}
```

Then you always deal with `IPostable` in a batch.

> how do I return a specific post by Id

According to the design above, you can easily get a `IPostable` instance by its id, since id is one of its property, and return strongly-typed instance by judging its `PostType` property:

```
public IPostable GetPost(Guid id)
{
    //id is a property of IPostable, so everything is easy
}

//you can easily get the real type
public T GetPost<T>(Guid id)
{
    IPostable post = GetThePostFirst();
    if (post.PostType == PostType.Photo) return (Photo)IPostable;
    //etc.
}
```